# Is it okay to execute multiple queries inside onCreate?

Tags: android

Hi I'm kinda new to SQLite for Android. I'm just wondering if it's okay to execute multiple queries inside the onCreate method for the DatabaseHelper? Can this affect the performance of the app?

DatabaseHelper.class:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("query");
        db.execSQL("query");
        db.execSQL("query");
        db.execSQL("query");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in executing multiple queries. but couple of recommendations

1. Use `Room`, which is a wrapper created by Android dev team on top of `SqLite` ([Link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room))
2. Use a thread for every IO operations, don't ever do IO operations on Android main thread. (Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html))
3. Minimise the number queries if possible as it is costly

Comment: I tried 'Room' and it's good on handling the queries. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is ok, but you need to handle all possibly long running and heavy tasks on another thread to not block UI and display progress or empty view in the meantime

Comment: Okay I'll take note of this. Thank you very much!